# How to get null value from an empty field in a form?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form with a text field which is stored in a nullable column in database. My problem is when the user let the field blank. I need to store it as a null value, but it is stored as an empty string.

Blade:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'PecaController@store', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    {!! Form::text('nome', old('nome')) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('descricao', old('descricao'), array('rows' => 3)) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Peca::create([
        'nome' => $request->input('nome'),
        'descricao' => $request->input('descricao')
    ]);

    return redirect(action('PecaController@index'));
}
```

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 they have introduced Middleware `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` that can do that for you.

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.html

You may want to enable that or just re-create it if you're on older version and don't want to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should define a mutator for that attribute.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators

```
public function setNomeAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['nome'] = $value !== '' ? $value : null;
}
```

You should define it for any attribute you want on your model class.

Comment: This is a good strategy, but I would need to do it for every attribute in the code. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: ConvertEmptyStringsToNull would be the right answer here